# django-mptt get full tree from table

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm using the app django-mptt to store a small tree structure.
In django view, how can I query the entire table in a **single query**, to get a queryset/list with each instance having a children attribute?

So I would like to do:

```
groups = SongGroup.objects.all().values()
for group in groups:
   group['children'] # list of children
```

But as I see in the docs, get_children() will trigger another query? Which I want to avoid, since I've already used all() to query the entire table.

I couldn't find a way in the docs to get an actual tree like structure from the table.
My model:

```
class SongGroup(MPTTModel):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

Comment: Use `SongGroup.objects.all().prefetch_related('children')` and use `group.children.all()` this won't query again, this is a eager loading not lazy load. So this is optimized, but if you use `filter()` instead of `all()` it will become lazy load and that will be bad. Another option query and use recursion to get tree like structure in dictonary.

Comment: how much levels prefetch_related will get?

Comment: All levels related to `children` which has this relation, don't worry this should work regardless of levels